# Wav player in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, wav, audio-player

Well I guess I have a tricky question. I'd like to open a wav file in MATLAB, and be able to listen to it and to see the signal on a plot at the same time (just like in a classic audio player). I'm an occasional and it seems I can only find the sound function, which only read the signal.

Comment: it's not really a complete answer per se as I'm just looking into the same issue myself right now, but maybe, the MATLAB `audioplayer` function could help...

Answer (score 0):

As far as playing the sound, I'd look at the [wavread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html) help file which has a great example.  As far as synchronizing with a signal plot, I've not seen any built-in functions for that, it may be a little challenging to decide how long a pulse to display and then plot using something like:

```
hfile = 'tcbsswmu.wav';

% Read the data back into MATLAB, and listen to audio.
[y, Fs, nbits, readinfo] = wavread(hfile);
t = timer('TimerFcn',@(obj, event, string_arg) mycallback(1/Fs,y,0.10), 'Period',     0.10,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','TasksToExecute', floor( numel(y)/(0.10)));
sound(y, Fs);
start(t);
```

It's **not** pretty, and the indexes need some polish but it may be a good start.